# SPErrorInfo - The app <appid> does not have an endpoint or its endpoint is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have created a SharePoint Provider Hosted app using ASP.NET webforms. I am attempting to access a list within the SharePoint site that the app is installed on. When I attempt to get the clientContext:

```
var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(Context);
using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateAppOnlyClientContextForSPHost())
        {
            Web web = clientContext.Web;

            clientContext.Load(web);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            ListCollection listOfLists = web.Lists;
            clientContext.Load<ListCollection>(listOfLists);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        }
```

I receive a 401 not authorized error on the `clientContext.ExecuteQuery()` line.

When I inspect the appredirect.aspx call in Fiddler, I have no SPAppToken, and SPErrorInfo says `The app <appid> does not have an endpoint or its endpoint is not valid`.

I have not been able to locate any information about this error message, or where to set/check the endpoint, or even what endpoint it is referring to. How do I begin to troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to enable Windows Authentication, disabling Anonymous authentication, for the provider hosted app.

Answer (score 0):

This error is referring to the App Domain on the appinv.aspx page for the app in question. To resolve it,

- open appinv.aspx on the site you are trying to access with your app (the URL will be something like this- https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/{sitename}/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx)
- type in your app ID in the box labeled 'App Id:', then click 'Lookup'
- Add the host name of your app in the 'App Domain' box
- Put in the permission XML from your app manifest (so it has the correct permissions).
- Click the 'Create' button.